# What implications does 'move this discussion to chat' has?

Tags: support, chat

I'm trying to help [waterloo2005](https://askubuntu.com/users/20732/waterloo2005) with a kernel related [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53054/i-can-not-find-sys-kernel-debug-vgaswitcheroo-switch), at first it looked like a simple permission mistake, It seems I was wrong...

Right now, there's 8 comments of both me and [waterloo](https://askubuntu.com/users/20732/waterloo2005) trying to "debug" the situation and this subtle warning is bugging me:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

If I move the discussion to the chat what happens?

- A channel just for the question is created and linked back? And is [waterloo](https://askubuntu.com/users/20732/waterloo2005)
  notified?
- What if my "discussion" was with a user with less than 20
  reputation?

Comment: Whoa, all that information he has buried in the comments need to go into his question, then you wouldn't need so much chitchat. (I'll edit it up)

Comment: If the user you are helping has less than 20 reputation it will give an error when you actually try moving to chat. However, it will still recommend moving to chat even if the other user has <20 reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click that link, a chat room will be created for you and waterloo2005. Its name will be "Discussion between sergio91pt and waterloo2005".

The comments so far will be copied into it, and the question or answer will be linked to from the chat room as well. Once all this is done, there will be a "let us continue this discussion in chat" comment left on the post that links to the newly created chat room. The user you're inviting to a chat conversation will be notified.

If your discussion is with a user with less than 20 reputation (across Stack Exchange, not just on this site), he or she would not be able to participate in the chat. I believe the "move to chat" link would pop up anyway, but if you try to use it it will warn you that the other user doesn't have enough reputation and do nothing.